# Automapper only mapping certain properties

Tags: .net, vb.net, automapper

Using automapper i am mapping my ViewModel to my business object, however i want to map to an existing object instance and only map the properties on my view model. e.g.

ProductModel has id,name,code
ProductBusiness has id,name,code,dateadded

```vb
Function Add(ByVal model As ProducModel) As ActionResult
    dim _ProductBusiness = (Load ProductBusiness from db)

    dim newProductBusiness = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(Of Business.User)(model)
End Function
```

i want to somehow pass in the existing business object instance and only map the 3 properties that are on both objects, dateadded should stay the same as it was in the database.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you Create your mappings, you can ignore properties.

Don't know if your're looking for soemthing more sophisticated.

in c#

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductBusiness>()
.ForMember(target => target.dateadded, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

If you wan't something more generic, it's possible, but more details would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
    Public Sub MapIt(input As ProductModel, output As ProductBusiness)
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap(Of ProductModel, ProductBusiness)()
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(input, output)
    End Sub
```

But remember, **you don't need to call `CreateMap` every time**. **AutoMapper will ignore `dateadded`**. (***Haven't tested it, but i believe it'l do so***).

Or alternatively you can do this:

```
    Public Sub MapIt(input As c1, output As c2)
        AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap(input, output)
    End Sub
```

The second code is **same as the first one**. `DynamicMap` will call `CreateMap` for you.